# PHP auto increment inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

this is my first question here.
I'm facing a problem that is literally driving me crazy. I'm new to PHP and I feel that it is something really simple that I just can't figure out.

I have this code:

```
$busca_alimento = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alimentos");
if (empty($busca_alimento)) { 
    echo 'Nothing found';
}

$count = 0;

while ($alimento_informacoes = mysql_fetch_array($busca_alimento)) {

    $alimento_id[$count++] = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
    $alimento_categoria[$count++] = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
    $alimento_nome[$count++] = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
    $alimento_quantidade[$count++] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];

}
```

I want to fetch the ID, Categoria, Nome and Quantidade rows and store the data in those vars like this:

```
$alimento_id[1]
$alimento_categoria[1]
$alimento_nome[1]
$alimento_quantidade[1]
```

but what is happening is this:

```
$alimento_id[1]
$alimento_categoria[2]
$alimento_nome[3]
$alimento_quantidade[4]
```

Does anyone know what's happening and how can I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment $count one time only, then use it as a subscript.

```
while ($alimento_informacoes = mysql_fetch_array($busca_alimento)) {
    $count++;
    $alimento_id[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
    $alimento_categoria[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
    $alimento_nome[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
    $alimento_quantidade[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];

}
```

Depending on the initial value of $count and what value you want to use, you may need to move `$count++` to the end of the loop.

Comment: I moved the $count to the end of the loop and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like this better, and no increment needed:

```
while ($alimento_informacoes = mysql_fetch_array($busca_alimento)) {
  $alimento_id[]         = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
  $alimento_categoria[]  = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
  $alimento_nome[]       = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
  $alimento_quantidade[] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're incrementing it everytime. Increment it just once:

```
while ($alimento_informacoes = mysql_fetch_array($busca_alimento)) {
    // so first loop, its just zero, 0
    $alimento_id[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
    $alimento_categoria[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
    $alimento_nome[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
    $alimento_quantidade[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];
    // so before this line, its all zero
    $count++; // then increment
    // increment it after cycle is complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

increment `$count` only one time in the loop:

```
$alimento_id[++$count] = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
$alimento_categoria[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
$alimento_nome[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
$alimento_quantidade[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];
```

Comment: In this way, the other arrays will have different `$count` value than first, maybe you mean `++$count`

Answer (score 0):

```
$busca_alimento = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alimentos");
if (empty($busca_alimento)) { 
  echo 'Nothing found';
}

$count = 0;

while ($alimento_informacoes = mysql_fetch_array($busca_alimento)) {

$alimento_id[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['id'];
$alimento_categoria[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['categoria'];
$alimento_nome[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['nome'];
$alimento_quantidade[$count] = $alimento_informacoes['quantidade'];

$count++;
}
```